# sql select and insert with range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to insert like this. I know the start date

7 days dates for every users in selected user set

Name is selected from a table

```
SELECT NAME FROM USERS
```

I want to select the name from users and add Date to that and insert in to another table like below

```
Name        Date
----------------------
A           01/01/2014
A           02/01/2014
A           03/01/2014
B           01/01/2014
B           02/01/2014
B           03/01/2014
C           01/01/2014
C           02/01/2014
C           03/01/2014
```

Basically I need to get the above selected result to insert

I only know the start date so if I want to add 7 days then each user get 7 records

Thanks

Comment: does every user have to begin with the same date or it can be a different date ? btw, what are you trying to achieve with this ?

Comment: Thanks I got it please look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it thanks guys to look in to this here is the answer

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20140101', @EndDate DATE = '20140107' 
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) as Dates,
 Name FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr 
 FROM sys.columns c) nbrs,
 Users WHERE nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
 ORDER BY Name ASC, Dates ASC
```

Comment: Awesome how did you do it ?

Comment: from stackoverflow :)